# Cannot install whatsapp in android 2.3.4

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, installation

I've a quite old version of android in my smartphone. I use whatsapp regularly, except yesterday where I had to try to update, and I couldn't do it because I don't have enough space on my smartphone. I've removed whatsapp and try the reinstallation but it doesn't work... Is there anything I can do? I read that there's probably some procedure I could try using both root privileges (that I have) and an emulated terminal.

This is not the first time that happens, usually I just remove apps that I don't use, but now I don't really know what to do.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should know that WhatsApp is no longer supported on device bellow android 4.0. Newer update won't simply work. You should upgrade to a newer phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know that WhatsApp is no longer supported on devices running android 2.3 and below. Newer updates​ won't simply install. The support had to end on june, and we're on june.

You should consider upgrading to a newer phone.

However, in some exceptions, WhatsApp can be installed when you download directly the APK file.

Try downloading the file from [here](http://htpp://whatsapp.com/android).

Comment: That's exactly what I did at last (but not because of whatsapp, that was a side effect)

Answer (score 0):

Try to completely delete the Whatsapp folder form a file explorer and also locate and delete the data folder using a root explorer (ES File Explorer). Try again. Maybe even factory reset ans retry if you can afford to factory reset or maybe take a backup and factory reset anyway.
OR
Maybe earlier version of Whatsapp was small enough to fit on your phone and newer version is now heavier so there is no way for you to install it.

Comment: Shall I delete the whole "data" folder? are you sure that is safe?

Comment: I've downloaded the file explorer, and I'm looking through the "data" folder. It doesn't seem to me safe at all removing blindly the stuff. So if you could clarify why I may want to do that would help.

Comment: Don't delete​ that folder you'll mess things up

Comment: No I meant the whatsapp app folder inside data folder. It should go like "com.xxx.whatsapp"

Comment: I don't see how doing this will solve your problem! Check my answer and try what I suggested.